# ASP.NET Membership/SQL Server issue - missing data

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-membership

I am having an issue that I can't seem to figure out.  Hopefully somebody can point me in the right direction, or give me other ideas to look into.  I won't provide much code now because honestly I don't think it's a coding issue.

First, I have an ASP.NET 3.5 web application.  I am using ASP.NET Membership libraries for my authentication.  The data lies in a SQL Server 2005 database.

My application enables a user to fill out a request that gets saved in the database.  The page to fill out a request lies in a subfolder that contains the following web.config file (I want users to be authenticated before they fill out the request):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

A user is required to log on or create a new account to fill out a request.  When they submit a request, they get an email verification that it was submitted.  The recipient address of this email verification is collected using:

```
Membership.GetUser().Email
```

So far this all seems fairly elementary and has worked without a hitch.  However, I just receieved a few calls from our users of people who filled out the request and got the email, but the request could not be found in the system.  I had them forward me the confirmation emails so I could view the recipient address and find the user in the ASP.NET Membership tables.  However, I could not find the user based on the email, and I could find no trace of the Request in the database when I was given details on what they entered.

I have provided no method for users to delete their accounts or delete a request.  There is no method to change an email address or edit pertinent data.  The database is pretty locked down, with all queries being run through Stored Procedures.

Now, my question is, how in the heck is this possible?  The user needs to be authenticated to fill out the request, and I have the confirmation email with the email address which I can't find in the system.  The email address is gathered using the the method mentioned above, which to me proves that this user had to exist in the database with the specified email address at one time.

I really have no clue where to proceed from here.  Does anybody have an ideas on what to check?  I would appreciate any advice as I am stumped, and I can provide any additional info if needed.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can we see the code for the function that saves the record and then send the email?

Comment: It's a simple, staightforward stored procedure call, but flows through a multi-tiered system.  I'm not really sure that is pertinent because I can't track down the ASP.NET Membership data now even though the email was sent using the Membership.GetUser().Email call.  I know the email was sent, even though the form is secured as detailed above.

Comment: I assume you've also checked the database for LastActivity being set around the time the email was sent? I agree this is odd, because GetUser not only connects back to the database to read the users info, but also updates it with the time it was called...

Comment: THe problem is that the user's records no longer exist in the ASP.NET membership tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whew, problem solved.  The staging address was provided to the end user by the customer and the data was in the staging database.  Looks like all of my conspiracy theories about database integrity were false.  :-)

Thanks for all the suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

If I had to guess without seeing the code that is part of the registration process I would say there is some error in saving the record to the database but not in sending the email.  If both actions were wrapped in a transaction that might solve your problem, that way people wouldn't recieve an email unless the record was saved to the DB and vice versa.  Do you have any logging enabled that would show any errors saving to the DB?

Comment: Registering a new user is a separate process than filling out a request.  A new user is added with Membership.CreateUser(EmailAddressTextBox.Text.Trim(), PasswordTextBox.Text, EmailAddressTextBox.Text.Trim());.  I was trying to make the point that the user HAD to be existant if the email was sent because it was pulling the email address from the Membership tables.

Comment: And yes, I am logging all errors in the global.asax file, and there were not caught.

Answer (score 0):

I posted the comment asking for code first, because without the code this will be hard to answer, but two possibilities come to mind.  Either one would allow the email to be sent, but the data not being written tot he database:

1. (Not likely as it would be easy for you to spot and you'd have caught it by now) The code for sending the email is executed before saving to the database.
2. (more likely) There is a flaw in the error handling that will allow the email to be sent even if the DB save is in error, such as:

   try

   ```
   {
      SaveToDo();
   }
   catch(Exception ex)
   {

     // something here

   }
   SendEmail();
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was trying to make the point that the user HAD to be existant if the email was sent because it was pulling the email address from the Membership tables.  Also, the email is sent after the database save, and if there was an exception thrown it would have been caught and logged in the global.asax file.